# APIxu end_dt parameter is not working

Tags: weather-api

My problem is about the historical end_dt data from https://www.apixu.com.

I have purchased the gold plan just because of this note from pricing page (https://www.apixu.com/pricing.aspx):

- Note: Only one day history data is returned per call for Free and Silver Plan. Gold plan and above returns max 30 day data in one call by passing dt and end_dt parameter. Visit our request documentation section to learn more.

In the documentation page (https://www.apixu.com/doc/request.aspx) only mention that is needed to send the end date as the parameter end_dt, and it has to be greater than dt and 2015-01-01.

But when i call this link:
http://api.apixu.com/v1/history.json?key=XXXXX&q=-6.84948,-47.9634&dt=2017-01-01&end_dt=2017-01-31

Only returns the data of the day 2017-01-01 and not the 30 day data promissed. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: not yet, i am getting the data day by day until found the solution for this problem.